# Spring data repository junit Test

Tags: java, spring-data

I'm trying to test my application , the problem is that i have a repository interface which contains some methods  like this:

```
 public interface EmployeeDetailRepository extends   JpaRepository<EmployeeDetail, Integer> {

    public List<EmployeeDetail> employeeTasks(@Param("emp_id")  List<Integer> emp_id, @Param("flag") boolean Active);
   }
```

The query for this method is defined as a named-native-query in another xml file.
When i start any test , i have a fail to load ApplicationContext with this error:

```
 Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'employeeDetailRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is  org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException
  : No property employeeTasks found for type EmployeeDetail!
```

This error is shown  only when i start the test cases , when i start the application, nothing happened.
Any help will be much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you are trying to get the list of active employees in the tables and here is the query for you.

But the below explanation is for only one employee Id. But if you want to find out the list of the employees when you have given the list of Employee Id's I thikn you have to implement the method yourself.

```
public interface EmployeeDetailRepository extends   JpaRepository<EmployeeDetail, Integer> {

@Query("select e from EmployeeDetail e where emp_id=?1 and active=?2")
    public List<EmployeeDetail> employeeTasks(Integer emp_id, boolean active);
   }
```

However if you want the exact operation you have asked in your question you would have to implement the same. You may find how to do a custom implementation on [this page](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.8.0.RELEASE/reference/html/)

Thanks,
Abhijeet.

Comment: Thanks to all of you, effectively, the solution was so simple, i just add to my persistence.xml file this line of code:<mapping-file>META-INF/native-queries.xml</mapping-file> which load the file on startup.I could use the annotation mode as describe above but my queries are so long , that's why i defined them in a separate xml file.

Answer (score 1):

Clearly you go something wrong with your configuration because spring is trying to interpret method name.
Maybe you could annotate your EmployeeDetail with @NamedQuery. This worked well in my case.
It is well described [here](http://www.petrikainulainen.net/programming/spring-framework/spring-data-jpa-tutorial-three-custom-queries-with-query-methods/).